# How i can hide bottom navigator on ShellRoute?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, router

I'm creating an application with the bottom navigator.
I used a `ShellRoute` but our requirement is to hide bottom navigator on screen
For example:
main page can have bottom navigator when i go to another screen (such an user profile page)
I have to hide bottom navigator but i use `ShellRoute` and sub route in the same `ShellRoute`, it doesn't hide bottom navigator.

```
ShellRoute(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state, child) {
            return MainScreen(child: child);
          },
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/$dashboardRouteName',
              name: dashboardRouteName,
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomPageRouteBuilder.route(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                child: const DashboardScreen(),
              ),
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: leaveRequestRouteName,
                  name: '$dashboardRouteName/$leaveRequestRouteName',
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomPageRouteBuilder.route(
                    key: state.pageKey,
                    child: const LeaveRequestScreen(),
                  ),
                ),
                GoRoute(
                  path: switchHolidayRouteName,
                  name: '$dashboardRouteName/$switchHolidayRouteName',
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomPageRouteBuilder.route(
                    key: state.pageKey,
                    child: const SwitchHolidayScreen(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

after that, i separate sub route into general route like below:

```
  ShellRoute(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state, child) {
            return MainScreen(child: child);
          },
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/$dashboardRouteName',
              name: dashboardRouteName,
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomPageRouteBuilder.route(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                child: const DashboardScreen(),
              ),
            ),
....
 GoRoute(
          path: '/$switchHolidayRouteName',
          name: switchHolidayRouteName,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomPageRouteBuilder.route(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const SwitchHolidayScreen(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/$leaveRequestRouteName',
          name: leaveRequestRouteName,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomPageRouteBuilder.route(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const LeaveRequestScreen(),
          ),
        ),
```

and i use `context.go()`, it works but i can't back to previous screen with `context.pop()`.

anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 4):

This usually happens when the `page` doesn't know it's parent.

Specify that using `parentNavigatorKey` in `GoRoute`

#### Code Structure:

```
final _parentKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

|_ GoRoute
 |_ parentNavigatorKey = _parentKey    Specify key here
|_ ShellRoute
 |_ GoRoute
  |_ parentNavigatorKey = _shellKey    Specify key here
 |_ GoRoute
  |_ parentNavigatorKey = _shellKey    Specify key here
```

---

#### Suggestion

##### Your present code:

```
|_ShellKey
  |_GoRoute // needs bottomNav
  |_GoRoute // needs bottomNav
  |_GoRoute // doesn't need bottomNav
```

##### Change it to:

```
|_ShellKey
  |_GoRoute // needs bottomNav
  |_GoRoute // needs bottomNav
|_GoRoute // doesn't need bottomNav  Try to keep it outside the ShellKey
```

---

*Refer detailed code and explaination of bottom NavigationBar using `ShellRoute` and `GoRouter` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996767/13431819)*

Answer (score 3):

inside your main screen, where your navigation bar is defined, check your current location using `GoRouter.of(context).location`. if your location is not where bottomNavigationBar is suppose to show, then return Sizedbox or null , else return your BottomNavigationBar.

```html
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final location = GoRouter.of(context).location;
    print('goRouter Location $location');
    return Scaffold(
      body: widget.child,
      bottomNavigationBar: location != '/home' ? null : BottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: good to hear that. also, consider upvoting if this answer helps you to help others find the right solution too.

Answer (score 3):

I try this way, it works. use _navigatorKey and parentNavigatorKey

```
final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
...
ShellRoute(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state, child) {
            return MainScreen(child: child);
          },
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/$dashboardRouteName',
              name: dashboardRouteName,
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomPageRouteBuilder.route(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                child: const DashboardScreen(),
              ),
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: leaveRequestRouteName,
                  parentNavigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
                  name: '$dashboardRouteName/$leaveRequestRouteName',
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomPageRouteBuilder.route(
                    key: state.pageKey,
                    child: const LeaveRequestScreen(),
                  ),
                ),
                GoRoute(
                  path: switchHolidayRouteName,
                  parentNavigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
                  name: '$dashboardRouteName/$switchHolidayRouteName',
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomPageRouteBuilder.route(
                    key: state.pageKey,
                    child: const SwitchHolidayScreen(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: can you provide source code or how you navigate to/back to 'doesnt need bottom nav' screen